# Declare and assign result from stored procedure in one line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to declare and assign the result from an sp in **one statement**?
If we can do,

`DECLARE @lastid INTEGER = (SELECT MAX([Id]) FROM [ADVWKS].[dbo].[Account]);`

why cant we do the below one?

```
DECLARE @lastaccid INTEGER = (EXEC sp_GetGlobalVarVal 'LAST_ACCID');
```

So far you need one statement to declare the variable and one to execute the procedure and assign the variable as return, output, cursor etc. Can we do it in a single statement??

Comment: An SP is not a function. SP return values are not intended for data but status values, use output parameters instead - or if your SP doesn't perform any data updates/inserts/deletes then use a function instead of an SP.

Comment: Use a `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: well, the intention of the question is how to declare and assign it in one go. OUTPUT still requires a declare'd variable.

Comment: Not with an SP. Note you still `DECLARE` the variable when you set it's initial value using a `SELECT` too though. `DECLARE @I int = 1;` and `DECLARE @I int; SET @I = 1;` are synonymous.

Comment: The documentation for [`declare`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) allows an optional `= value` clause to assign an initial value in-line. It then refers to the documentation for [`Expressions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). There you'll find no mention of executing stored procedure to return a value. If you can wrap the SP in a scalar function, e.g. a UDF or CLR function, you're good to go. I suspect that constitutes >1 statement.

Comment: I do not know your SP, but this might be better solved with a VIEW or an iTVF. A stored procedure is designet **to do** something, while VIEWs or iTVFs are designed to retrieve values. All SPs which are just wrappers around a `SELECT` should not be SPs... It might help to show the code of your SP.

Comment: T-SQL is quite old compared to many languages you'll encounter these days and one area where this is quite obvious is the lack of *orthogonality*. Just because two particular features work together doesn't mean you can expect that *similar* features will also work together in the same manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do the below because it is often the case that the return type for the stored procedure is a table. It would either execute, and run DML statements which wont return anything, or it would return data set. Now what you can do is to build a scalar value function instead of stored procedure and select from that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Another possibility is using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017#returning-data-using-a-return-code, but conceptually per article, this is only used for Return Codes, not really for the variable assignment or populating variables for different types, and do not forget, there is only values between 0 - 4.

Comment: Does that confirm it is not possible to declare and populate (not saying assign because that generally translates to var = sp form) a value to a variable using stored procedure in one statement?

Comment: @JimsonKannantharaJames I guess you would work out with the return code method, but overall, the concept is more complicated than that. If you know for sure that the value is basically integer, than you could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017#returning-data-using-a-return-code

Answer (score 0):

Use an `OUTPUT` parameter instead. This is very simplified, however:

```
CREATE PROC TEST_SP @I int, @O int OUTPUT AS

    SET @O = @I *5;

GO

DECLARE @Var int;
EXEC TEST_SP 1,@Var OUTPUT;
SELECT @Var;

GO
--CLEAN UP
DROP PROC TEST_SP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTPUT Parameters:

This is an example SP where the second variable (@Param_2) is defined as output Parameter

```
CREATE   PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP]
(
    @Param_1 int,
    @Param_2 int output
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Param_2 = 10 * @Param_1;
END
```

Now you can call the SP like this:

```
DECLARE @Value_1 INT = 42;
DECLARE @RetVal INT = 0;

SELECT @RetVal;
EXEC [dbo].[MySP] @Value_1, @Param_2 = @RetVal OUTPUT;
SELECT @RetVal;
```

The frist time you select @RetVal the value will still be 0. After the execution of the SP, @RetVal will be 420 (10 * 42 calcualted inside the SP):

```
-----------
0

(1 row affected)


-----------
420

(1 row affected)
```

TLDR: No :)